Exponential family expression for bivariate Gaussian
Consider a bivariate Gaussian distribution with the following density:
$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(x^2-2\rho xy+y^2)}$$
How can we write it in the exponential family form, i.e.
$$f(x,y) = e^{\eta_1 T_1(x,y)+\eta_2 T_2(x,y) - \psi(\eta_1,\eta_2)}h(x,y)$$
I can rewrite $f$ as
$$f(x,y) = e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(x^2+y^2) + \frac{\rho}{1-\rho^2}xy -\ln 2\pi - \frac{1}{2} \ln (1-\rho^2)}$$
So, seems like we can choose $\eta_1 = \frac{1}{1-\rho^2}$ and $\eta_2 = \frac{\rho}{1-\rho2}$. Then how can we recognize $\psi$? There is no unique way to write $\ln (1-\rho^2)$ as a function of $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$. For example, it is $-\ln \eta_1$ or $\ln (1-\frac{\eta_2^2}{\eta_1^2})$. Which one should we use?

Could you please explain why you introduce two parameters $(\eta_1,\eta_2)$ for a one parameter family (parameterized only by $\rho$)??

@whuber Yes. I firstly tried to express it as an one parameter family, but I failed to recognize the natural parameter and sufficient statistics. Is there a way to do that?

Simply look at $$\log f(x,y;\rho) = (-1/(2(1-\rho^2), \rho/(1-\rho^2))\cdot(x^2+y^2, xy) + (\log(2\pi)) + (-\log(1-\rho^2)/2)$$ and compare with the exponential family formulation, such as given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family.

@whuber I see. I just noticed that this is a curved one, i.e. the map from $\rho$ to $eta$ is not bijection. Thanks!

@whuber Sorry for the follow up question. How can we express it in the canonical form, i.e. parameterize it use $\eta = (-1/(2(1-\rho^2)), \rho/(1-\rho^2))$?
